# How does reputation work? How can I gain privileges?

Tags: soporte, stackexchange

Right now I have a 41 reputation on Spanish.

The next privilege is to comment everywhere when I reach a 50 reputation.

I want to know how I can reach that reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Exchange's system is based on reputation. Depending on reputation, you have different privileges.

The privileges are listed in [Help Center > Privileges](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) and you gain them once you reach that certain reputation threshold.

You can read about the reputation itself in Meta Stack Exchange's [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/209901), which I copy here:

> ### What does *Reputation* do?
>
> As a registered user, your reputation on the site is a part of your
>   identity on the site. It reflects, to an extent, your familiarity with
>   the site, the amount of subject matter expertise you have and the
>   level of respect your peers have for you. It can generally only be
>   gained when other users of the site approve of the content you
>   provide.
>
> Reputation also determines a user’s privileges within the system. As
>   you gain more reputation, the system learns to trust you and bestows
>   new privileges upon you that low-reputation users cannot access.
>
> As users gain reputation, they gain abilities and responsibilities.
>   The required reputation can vary slightly between different Stack
>   Exchange sites ; see [your site’s `/privileges` page](/privileges) for
>   specifics. **Common privilege levels for new sites, public beta sites
>   and “normal” sites are described [here](/q/58587/).**
>
> ### How can users gain or lose *Reputation?*
>
> Users gain or lose reputation based on the quality of their
>   interactions with the system and other community members. The primary
>   reason for reputation change is voting. Posts which are upvoted
>   increase their authors’ reputation; the reverse is true for posts
>   which are downvoted. Upvotes are more heavily weighted than downvotes.
>
> Posts which have [Community Wiki status](/q/11740) are exceptions to
>   the reputation rules; votes and [acceptances](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35928/2-on-accepting-answers-something-is-wrong-with-my-account-on-so/35930#35930) do not grant
>   reputation; bounties, however, still do.
>
> #### You gain reputation when:
>
> - One of your posts is upvoted: **+10**
> - One of your answers is *accepted* by the author: **+15**
> - You *accept* an answer, not written by you, to a question of yours: **+2**
> - A [suggested edit of yours is approved](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work): **+2** (up to a total of +1000 per user)
> - One of your answers is awarded a bounty by the user offering the bounty: **+ full bounty amount**
> - One of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: **50% or 100% of the bounty amount** (see [bounty FAQ](/a/16067) for details)
> - You *associate accounts* of two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts has 200 or more reputation:
>     **+100** on each site (awarded only once per site) (this reputation bonus does *not* count toward the required 10 reputation to answer
>     protected questions)
>
> #### You lose reputation when:
>
> - One of your posts is downvoted: **−2**
> - A post where you had successfully *suggested an edit* has been *deleted* (reputation page shows the cause as *removed*): **−2**
> - The account of *a user who was the final approver of a suggested edit you made* [has been
>     deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311413) (reputation page
>     shows the cause as *User was removed*): **−2**
> - You downvote an answer: **−1**
> - One of your *accepted* answers loses *accepted* status (i.e. unaccepted): **−15**
> - You *unaccept* an answer written by someone else to one of your own questions: **−2**
> - You place a bounty on a question: **− full bounty amount**
> - One of your posts receives 6 [spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work) or [rude or abusive](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work) (formerly known as *offensive* flags): **−100**
>
> * Downvoting a Community Wiki answer does not deduct reputation from
>   the voter.
>
> #### Additionally:
>
> - All users start with one reputation point.
> - No user's reputation may drop below one point; if an action would cause a user's reputation to drop below one point, that user only
>     loses enough reputation to drop to one point ([source](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1)), and the
>     remaining penalty or loss is waived.
> - You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits in any given
>     [day](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start).
>     Bounties and the bonuses for accepting and accepted answers are
>     counted separately
>     ([source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/)).
>     Reputation “lost” from the reputation cap is not awarded on following
>     days. Additionally, if you hit the cap and later lose reputation,
>     previous votes do not fill in the difference, although later votes
>     will push it to the cap again.
> - If a vote is removed, everyone's reputation is recalculated as if the vote was never cast.
> - If a vote is cast before a post becomes Community Wiki, but is removed after the post becomes CW, the *removal* does not affect
>     anyone's reputation ([source](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29088/downvote-removed-score-of-downvoted-user-unchanged)).
> - Before May 2011, downvoting questions cost the downvoter one reputation point ([source](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/90927/232857)). (Since May 2011, there is no cost for
>     downvoting questions.)
> - Deleting and undeleting posts may reverse reputation effects as well, if these posts have votes. Actions previously taken on deleted
>     posts cease to affect reputation within five minutes ([source](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes)),
>     unless the post meets both the following criteria (in which case the
>     reputation effects will be permanent) ([source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)):
>
>   - The post had a score of at least +3
>   - The post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days
> - Accepting your own answer does not gain you any reputation.
> - [Voting reversal](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19920/how-does-the-so-voter-fraud-detection-mechanism-work)
>     as a result of [serial
>     voting](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)
>     will return lost or gained reputation.
> - If a user who voted for one or more of your posts or who approved any of your suggested edits gets their account deleted, it *may* cause
>     your reputation to change as if their votes were never cast. If this
>     changes your reputation, the change will be shown as "User was
>     removed".
>
>   - This [does not happen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126471) if the user has cast a lot of votes, such that removing all of them would
>       be highly disruptive to a lot of users. In that case, the account's
>       deletion will be held up so that staff can review the user's voting
>       record. If, upon review, employees come across some reason that votes
>       should not be preserved (e.g. the user was involved in voting fraud),
>       they'll be removed as normal; otherwise, they will be preserved. If
>       you see a "User was removed" change in your history, it either means
>       that the user hadn't cast enough votes to trigger such a review, or
>       staff made the explicit decision not to preserve the votes.
> - A script that runs occasionally fixes inconsistencies in reputation, which may be caused by bugs/glitches not mentioned here. This can
>     change your reputation in certain cases.
> - Upvoted comments do not affect reputation.
>
> #### When everyone is at 1, where does the reputation start?
>
> There are four ways a new user can earn their first bit of reputation:
>
> - Make a post that gets upvotes. No reputation is required to make posts, and the rep loss from downvotes is waived if it causes your
>     reputation to drop below 1.
> - Users come from another site in the network where they start with 100 reputation (if they have a linked account with 200+ reputation)
>     (this [doesn't give the ability to answer protected
>     questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user))
> - Users have their answers accepted or are the ones accepting answers from other users (+15 and +2 respectively)
> - Suggested edits are approved (the original poster has a binding vote on suggested edits if they are not yet approved or even rejected)

Answer (score 2):

This site is quite low traffic so it does take a long time to acquire reputation compared with the high traffic sites. My impression is that at the moment traffic is even lower.

You have asked quite a few questions which have not been up-voted so perhaps look at them and see if there are any which you could edit to clarify what you wanted. Note also that if you like the answer to any of them you should accept it by clicking the green tick (US=check) mark. This is kind to the people who answered and also gives you a small amount of extra reputation.