# What steps can I take if SE is no longer accepting questions from my account?

Tags: soporte, preguntas

I have asked [eighteen questions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/26420/arunabh-bhattacharya?tab=questions) so far. But Spanish SE [is not accepting any more questions from my account](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans). So, I need to improve my existing questions, so that I can ask more questions. So, how can I improve my existing questions?

Comment: See [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: Apart from the good advices given by Charlie following the post @mdewey provides, you should also consider accepting some answers. It is a way to thank people who provided answers as well as indicating that the question was solved. Further readings: [How do I ask a good question?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and all the [Asking section in the Help Center](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/asking) in general.

Comment: You should also listen to mdewey's advice in your other meta question ['Reputation to Vote Down'](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4356/5481). His advice highlights something we already warned you about via comments in your questions, and that you should listen to: those downvoted questions sometimes ask for the rule or rationale about something that is just a coincidental fact or a feature of any language (or at least seems like it, and the question is not researched well enough to lead to believe that those premises are not coincidental facts). I think this is the key of this problem

Comment: In fact on May 19 [I gave the OP advice about improving questions](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4341/how-does-reputation-work-how-can-i-gain-privileges/4343#4343). Perhaps it was not clear but in any event it did not seem to help.

Comment: The OP just left a link to this meta questions on one of their questions: [Anagramas en español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35317/5481), from July 22 were I gave some advice as well (which was either not useful or ignored). I think I'll "close the loop" by adding the reference here, but there my advice was that the question in particular was too broad (`I just wanted to know some examples of anagrams`) and, while downvotes could be reverted, I don't think that the question is likely to be edited to be on-topic if it's not by changing the question substantially.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [post linked by mdewey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/350184) is quite informative. There's nothing I can add to it but I would like nonetheless to copy here some paragraphs.

> Automatic bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action, you will never be allowed to freely post again. The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways.

It seems that you have no other choice but to try to improve your questions. Note the emphasis on "improve". Deleting your questions will not remove the ban, you need to improve them. Many of your questions, as noted before, try to ask about things that are just mere coincidences. As an example, [the last one](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35473/12637) (which I see you have deleted) tried to ask about why many nouns have synonyms of both masculine and femenine genders. That's just a matter of probability as half of the nouns are masculine in Spanish and the other half is feminine. Or are they? Maybe you can undelete and rephrase the question to "what is the percentage of masculine nouns in Spanish and what is the percentage of feminine ones?", so you can then calculate the probabily of a specific synonym to be of a gender or another.

Another example: you asked about why ["baca" and "baja"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35331/12637) have opposite meanings but are so similar (just another coincidence). Maybe you could change the question just to "what is the etymology of 'baca' and when did it start to be used in Spanish?" and ask a similar question for "bajo, a" and just reach your own conclusions. Just try to rephrase your questions to avoid asking for coincidences.

> Moderators cannot lift the ban.

This means that the ban removal depends exclusively on you, we moderators cannot do anything about this.

> Do note that rewriting an existing question into a substantially different question is frowned upon. Your edits should not negate or invalidate existing answers. The fixed post should fundamentally be about the same issue and topic, and the existing answers should still apply to it.

In the case the question you are going to edit has no answers yet then I suppose it's safe to change it substantially. I'll turn a blind eye in those cases, but be careful with the questions that already have answers.

One last thing, if you want, flag any post you edit for moderator attention and I'll write a comment asking people to remove the negative votes if the rephrased question deserves it. I hope you will get that annoying ban removed. Good luck!

Comment: Why as my question https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/35331/what-is-the-etymology-of-baca-and-baja-which-seem-to-be-antonyms-with-a-single-letter-of-difference? been marked as off-topic?

Comment: I have to discuss something about the two words "baca" and "baja". I tried searching on Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=spanish+%22baca%22+%2B+%22baja%22&oq=S&aqs=chrome.1.69i60j69i59j69i57j69i59j69i60l3j69i65.1968j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 But, I did not get any good results.

Comment: When I do not find any good results on Google regarding a topic, I decide to post a discussion on StackExchange. Currently, I do not know any other sites to post discussions.