# My recent question

Tags: soporte

I have a question about my Spanish Language & Usage Stack Exchange post: [Are there consistent rules for pronouncing "c", "j", "s", "x", and "z"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/39967/are-there-consistent-rules-for-pronouncing-c-j-s-x-and-z)

So far, this is the third new question I have asked on Spanish Stack Exchange following the meta question at [What steps can I take if SE is no longer accepting questions from my account?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4357/what-steps-can-i-take-if-se-is-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-my-account) and I tried to mimic the structure of the question at [Are there consistent rules for pronouncing "c" and "g"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/6883/are-there-consistent-rules-for-pronouncing-c-and-g) and ask a similar question  from a different perspective. But my question is downvoted to -2 after I set a bounty on it. I asked this question two days ago and I have not received any answers. I have only received a comment. I just wanted to know what has been going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Plagiarism

You have copied 99% of the text of [another question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/6883/24236). According to the FAQs, **plagiarism** on SE is [defined as](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160078/643262)

> any copying and pasting of any amount of text or code that wasn't written by you is plagiarism if you try, explicitly or implicitly, to pass it off as your own work.

Of course, this definition is too strict and impractical, but I think most will agree that 99% is too much.

#### Duplicate question

Aside from that issue, your [question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39967/24236) is (**emphasis** added by me)

> Are there any rules I could build into the software that would enable me to know **where "c" is to be pronounced as "th" and where as "s"**?
>
> Similary, are there any rules I could build into the software that would enable me to know **where "s" is to be pronounced as "th" and where as "s"**?

This is, in my opinion, an exact duplicate of the question [Distribution of Spanish speakers regarding 's' and 'c' pronunciation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26/24236), which has very detailed answers with maps of how "s" and "c" are pronounced in each Spanish-speaking region. These maps answer your question fully, and there is not much more we can say. This is a language site, so we are not going to write software.

As I [prefer to let the community decide on closing questions](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4403/24236), I did not close the question or even say that it should be closed. To help you find the answer, I added a comment with a link to the duplicate question that perfectly answers the question you posed (see bold above). Your reaction to this was to ignore the provided link and put a bounty on the question.

I suppose the downvotes are either because of plagiarism or because you are not satisfied with my provided link to an answer to the questions you wrote (so it is really unclear what you actually want to know). Maybe clarifying why the linked answers do not help you would be better than setting a bounty.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments in your question note, people think that your question is more a programming question rather than a question about the Spanish language. You ask about rules you can build into your language, which may lead people to think you need programming tips. Also, if you only need to tell apart the regions with *ceceo* from the regions with *seseo*, wimi pointed you to [another question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26/12637) which asked the same. If you want to know how you can manage to translate that country/region list into your particular programming language, that's indeed a question for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

There is nothing wrong with getting negative votes in a question, I've had them sometimes. There is nothing personal in it, it's just that maybe you need to rephrase your question to make it more suitable for our site. What's really important is that you get the answers you need. If people are not understanding your question or what you need, edit it so when can better help you. If you think the question wimi linked helps you, just mark your question as a duplicate of the linked one.

Just remember we are here to help. :-)

Comment: So that means https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/6883/are-there-consistent-rules-for-pronouncing-c-and-g should also be migrated to https://stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya no. Both questions can be answered by just stating the rules, based either on word or region, without programming considerations. The difference between your question and the linked question is that your question has already been asked and answered before, and [that one](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/6883/24236) had not.