# Question closed as off-topic two weeks after I accept an answer

Tags: discusión, soporte

My question at [What rules do I determine for pronouncing "c", "j", "l", "s", "x", and "z"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/39967/what-rules-do-i-determine-for-pronouncing-c-j-s-x-and-z) has a very long history. I first had to ask the meta question at [My recent question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4442/my-recent-question). Then I edited my question. Later, I received one answer. I accepted the answer. However, two weeks later, my question is closed as off-topic. The mods who answered my other meta question were not the ones to close the question. However, 5 other community members decided to close the question. The answers in my other meta question say that my question is a duplicate. But, my question above is closed as off-topic and not as duplicate of [Distribution of Spanish speakers regarding 's' and 'c' pronunciation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26/distribution-of-spanish-speakers-regarding-s-and-c-pronunciation). Can anyone here tell why the question was not closed as duplicate, but was closed as off-topic?

Comment: Closing this as a duplicate of your other Meta question because all your answers are there. If you want this Meta question to be reopened, please [edit] this question to clearly state why the answers in the [linked duplicate](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4442/24236) do not convince you.